# Did Chrome 40 break justify-content CSS overriding?

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox, css-specificity

I noticed with today's Chrome 40 update that `justify-content` **does not seem to get properly overriden** by subsequent style declarations.

See [this fiddle](http://jsbin.com/nocoperimu/2/edit) for an example:

```
  <div class="flex-parent">
    <div class="flex-child"></div>
    <div class="flex-child"></div>
  </div>
```

and

```
.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; left: 0;

  /*
     IT SHOULD BE POSSIBLE TO SAFELY REMOVE
     THESE TWO LINES BECAUSE THEY ARE OVERRIDEN:
  */
  background: yellow;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-parent {
  /* Overriding background: it works! */
  background: green;

  /* Overriding justify-content: NOPE ;-( */
  justify-content: space-between;
}


.flex-child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: skyblue;
}
```

Firefox (override works):

[image]

Chrome 40 (override seems to be broken):

[image]

Am I correct in my assumptions or do I horribly misunderstand CSS? Note that this doesn't have to do with prefixes: Chrome supports unprefixed `justify-content`, and if it didn't work, there wouldn't be any difference when commenting out rules in first selector.

> Update: filed as https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=451387

Comment: Filed as https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=451387

Comment: Looks like its linked to this issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=449887

Comment: so? the solution? is a chrome bug (and we had to wait next update) or we had to modify our css?

Comment: @Radar155 It is a bug. Might be fixed in Chrome 41: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=449887#c11

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are entirely correct in your understanding of the cascade. If you look in the Web Inspector, you'll see the `justify-content: center` declaration struck out, but only when you uncheck it (in a similar fashion as commenting it out) can you get Chrome to ignore it.

Perhaps they accidentally broke something in a change between Chrome 39 and 40, as they have a really irritating habit of doing, but I have no idea what.

---

From the [issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=449887) that rwacarter linked to, apparently they did something funky with their cascade resolution code in order to accommodate certain changes to the Flexbox spec, which seems to be the cause for this. Again, I don't claim to understand their reasons for doing so, but they seem to have a habit of rewriting things here and there that result in regressions all over the place. Good thing Chrome is on an evergreen rapid release cycle, eh?

Comment: Thank you! I filed an issue with Chromium. Kinda weird that something so basic broke for a particular property, but then, I never wrote browsers..

Answer (score 3):

Definitely looks to be a bug, and a very serious/annoying one at that!

I've written a hack to help us get through it. **You'll only want to run this for affected chrome versions** and might want to further tailor and test it for your application:

```
$('body *').each(function(i, el){
    var justifyContents = $(el).css('justify-content').split(' ');
    var flexFlows = $(el).css('flex-flow').split(' ');
    if (flexFlows[0] == 'row' && justifyContents.length > 1) {
        if (justifyContents[0] == 'space-between' || justifyContents[0] == 'flex-start') {
            $(el).css('justify-content', justifyContents[0]+' left');
        } else if (justifyContents[0] == 'flex-end') {
            $(el).css('justify-content', justifyContents[0]+' right');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: which should be something like: if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome/40') > -1) { ... }

Comment: Excelente soluciont, this work for me but in angularjs version

Comment: just a heads up, it looks like this is still an issue for chrome/41 (at least on mac?) -- can just change the version detection for 'chrome/4' for all versions 40-49

Answer (score 1):

This is an angularjs implementation for script posted by @Mike T

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('flexChromeFix', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, fn) {

            var justifyContents = element.css('justify-content').split(' ');
            var flexFlows = element.css('flex-flow').split(' ');
            if (flexFlows[0] == 'row' && justifyContents.length > 1) {
            if (justifyContents[0] == 'space-between' || justifyContents[0] == 'flex-start') {
                element.css('justify-content', justifyContents[0] + ' left');
            } else if (justifyContents[0] == 'flex-end') {
                element.css('justify-content', justifyContents[0] + ' right');
            }
        }

        }
    };
});
```