# How to use flexbox with media queries fix overlapping justify content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Flexbox seems to have a bug when you try to override a previous applied justify content parameter.  What I want to do is justify content centered, but after a certain width apply a media query to the same item to justify content space between.  The effect is that justify content space between doesn't override the original centering but instead applies additional to the original style.  The result is items disappearing off the screen. Examples:
Original style:

```
.header {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
}
```

Then apply a media query:

```
.header {
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -moz-box-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

The result is not what you would expect, as if you set justify content space between on the original style.  Instead its as if center is still applied, and it tries to justify content space between ontop of the centering already happening, instead of removing centering and applying justify content space between.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28203658/chrome-not-properly-overriding-justify-content-for-flex-box

Comment: Can you post the HTML, and the media query?