# Chrome v41+ performance issue with display: none; on lots of nodes

Tags: css, google-chrome

I've recently noticed Chrome puking when applying `display: none;` to lots of nodes:

[CodePen example](http://codepen.io/mattdietsche/pen/JomjWx)

In the CodePen above, you can see the lag when toggling `display: none;` on 1000 elements. If you bump the 1000 to 3000 and toggle it again, the tab will hang completely. The same code works without any lag in Safari, and I'm 90% sure this was working fine in Chrome until the last month or so, so I'm guessing this is a recent Chrome bug. Has anyone else run into this and found a work around? (I have web app functionality that renders 3000+ elements, hides them all with CSS, and then shows them on demand with JS. Currently the page won't even load.)

Edit: Should have mentioned I'm seeing this in Chrome 41.0.2272.76 and Canary 43.0.2318.0. This does appear to be a bug that appeared somewhere in Chrome 41.x and has been reported.

```js
$("button.hide").on("click",function(){
  $("div.wrap").toggleClass("hide");
});
```

```css
.wrap.hide p {
  display: none;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='hide'>toggle 'display: none;'</button>
<!-- * This just creates a div containing 1000 <p> tags */ -->
<div class='wrap'>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <p>4</p>
  ...
  <p>998</p>
  <p>999</p>
  <p>1000</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Noticing no performance issue in chrome version 40.0.2214.115 m with 100,000 elements.

Comment: I just updated to Version 41.0.2272.89 m and I'm noticing the lag issue also

Comment: Like @pschueller, worked fine with v40, but upgraded and experiencing performance issue. How does Chrome keep getting worse?

Comment: Just reported the issue. Added this question URL to the ticket. Hope they figure it out.

Comment: [Never change, Chrome.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911052/odd-behavior-of-first-letter-in-chrome/28911182#28911182) Oh, wait...

Comment: No issue on Chromium 40.0.2214.111 on Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit).

Comment: Just updated Chrome (to 43.0.2337.0 canary) and it's fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a workaround. Use { height: 0; } instead of { display: none; } and { height: initial; } instead of { display: block; }.

I used it when I faced the same problem with 1300+ items in Chrome.

Comment: To better replicate display: none based the given example, you'd also want to use { overflow: hidden; margin: 0; } on the hidden elements.  This is a legit work-around as there is no lag, and will tide me over until the patch makes it to Chrome.

Comment: Should mention that this wont work with inline elements.

Answer (score 0):

I personally fixed this exact problem using the CSS property `will-change: transform;` in my element, which informs the browser that the element will have an animation, or a *change*.

Now it works like a charm!